# Helping New Contributors to understand how the answers work

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Looking for answers about a New Contributor who asked upvotes for his question, I fell into this question in Meta:

[Is it "ethical" to ask upvote the answer if the author of the question pretty satisfied?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/949/120647)

I read all the answers, but I don't think I have found a valid solution, only alternatives.

I have several answers that have not been validated as the right one, and I understand the reasons. But faced with such a big obviousness like the example below, I wonder if there is a more practical solution. (BTW, the difference between the upvote and the OP comment is around 24h, that's why I think the upvote doesn't come from the OP).

[Seeking help for this script Font Name](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114221/120647)

Among the answers to the @Ilan's question appears the possibility that the New Contributor doesn't know how GDSE works. It's understandable too.

Because of that I entered into the supposed situation of asking a question and it is true, there is only a kind of alert about how to make questions in **How to Ask** but nothing about how to understand or act to the answers: **How to receive an Answer**, where explaining everything about an answer.

[image: How to ask]

I think as important is the information about how to ask questions, which is the objective of the site, is also explaining the importance of validating right answers, or at list don't live them open and indicate that a comments like "have a great day" does not help at all.

Having a direct link to this *How to receive an Answer* field could help the people who answer to insert it in a comment when getting just a "thanks!" as validation.

My apologies if this already exists and I didn't know how to find it.

Comment: Do you mean this topic on Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Exactly, I think it should be more visible and at the moment of asking the question.

Comment: This strikes me more like a question for big Meta since we all share the same infrastructure.

Comment: From MSE yesterday: [Can we find a way to link new users to /help/someone-answers when they receive an answer for the first time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314694/307988)

Comment: @Cai This means I am not the only one with the same suggestion. Comparing with the other sites, I don't know if there the right answers are as evident as in the case of font identification in GDSE.